# How to write Cipher.getInstance("DES"); in jni?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I would like to change

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
```

into cpp code in jni.How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JNIEnv *jni; //Comes from somewhere
jclass cl = jni->FindClass("javax/crypto/Cipher");
jmethodID MID = jni->GetStaticMethodID(cl, "getInstance", "(Ljava/lang/String)Ljavax/crypto/Cipher;");
jstring s = jni->NewStringUTF("DES");
jobject cipher = jni->CallStaticObjectMethod(cl, MID, s);
```

That's omitting error handling.

Comment: Thank you very much!I make a mistake that I write CallStaticObjectMethod(cl, MID, s) to CallObjectMethod(cl, MID, s).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use native code for encryption, e.g. OpenSSL.

Mandatory warning: don't use DES.

Comment: Because a the key is pretty short, and can be brute forced in under a day. Plus there are more effective attacks.